# How to determine the best-fit magnetic dipole Gauss coefficient in a shifted coordinate system?

Tags: magnetic-fields, coordinate-systems, magnetic-moment, dipole, spherical-harmonics

## Introduction

A planetary magnetic field $\vec{B}$ can be described outside of the planet using Gauss coefficients $g_n^m$ and $h_n^m$ and a spherical harmonic expansion:

$$\vec{B} \;=\; -\vec{\nabla} V(r,\theta,\phi)$$

and

$$V(r,\theta,\phi) \;=\; \sum_{n=1} \sum_{m=0}^l R_p \left(\frac{R_p}{r}\right)^{n+1} \big[g_n^m \cos(m\phi) + h_n^m \sin(m\phi) \big] P_n^m(\cos\theta) \text{,}$$

where $R_p$ is the planetary radius and $P_n^m(\cos\theta)$ are the [associated Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials).

If we assume the magnetic field is axially symmetric, then only the $m=0$ terms remain:

$$\begin{align} V(r,\theta,\phi) \;=&\; \sum_{n=1} R_p \left(\frac{R_p}{r}\right)^{n+1} g_n^0 P_n^0(\cos\theta) \\ =&\; \sum_{n=1} R_p \left(\frac{R_p}{r}\right)^{n+1} g_n^0 P_n(\cos\theta) \text{,}\end{align} $$

where $P_n^0(\cos\theta) = P_n(\cos\theta)$ are the [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).

## My Question

Suppose I have the axisymmetric Gauss coefficients (say, $g_n^0$ for $1 \le n \le N$) for a given planet in a coordinate system centered on the planet. Let's suppose the magnetic equator is located northward from the planet's equatorial plane by a distance $\Delta z$, which implies the magnetic field is not symmetric about the planet's equator.

**I want to treat the magnetic field as a dipole, probably in a coordinate system shifted northward along the polar axis by $\Delta z$. How could I calculate from those coefficients the "best-fit" dipole field in the shifted coordinate system?**

Comment: Transform the field to Cartesian coordinates and make a shift.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: How would I do that if I only have the Gauss coefficients for the unshifted field? Sure, I could transform the coordinates and vector components, but I'd still have the higher order terms. If I shifted only the dipole term, I'd lose the effect of the higher-order terms on the shifted dipole. How would I get the dipole term in the shifted coordinate system?

Comment: You have a function $V(r,\theta , \phi )$. Transform this function to Cartesian coordinates $V(x,y,z)$. Make a shift $z=z'+\Delta z$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev That’s what you said in your first comment. My reply asked a question. Shifting coordinate systems — by itself — doesn’t give a new value or expression for a coefficient in the unshifted frame. (I actually do as much already in a similar problem.) Shifting coordinate systems is trivial. I don’t know how that would affect the dipole term. Perhaps it would help if you expressed your intentions mathematically: something like $g_1^{0,’} = f(g_1^0)$, where the prime denotes the shifted frame.

Answer (score 0):

First write the equations with the higher order terms (https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/51307/the-path-of-a-particle-in-planets-magnetic-field-doesnt-not-seem-to-change-wit/51313#51313). once you have done that all you need to do is replace the coordinates (r,theta, phi or x,y,z) with the transformed ones as show below

I am not re typing since it is nicely written in the papers.
[image: shifted dipole coordinate]
[image]
J.W. Vriesema, et al. Icarus 344 (2020) 113390
Also look at
Swisdak, M., 2006. Notes on the Dipole Coordinate System. pp. 1–6. arXiv:0606044
http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0606044